# merging pandas dataframes on multiple columns - error about levels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm merging my two dataframes below on two fields.

```
successes = pd.merge(failures, successes, left_on=['name', 'project_name'], right_on=['name', 'project_name'], how='left')
```

But I get this error - can anyone help me out please?

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py:643: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result (1 levels on the left,2 on the right)
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
```

Comment: Please post samples of  your two DFs

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you merge DataFrames with different levels of column indices.
Artificial example below reproduces your warning:

```
import pandas as pd
# a has 2 level column index
a = pd.DataFrame({("name_0","name_01"):[1,2,3,4],
                 ("name_0","name_02"):[4,3,2,1]})
# b has 1 level column index
b = pd.DataFrame({"name_0":[10,2,30,40],
                 "name_1":[40,30,20,10]})

# Notice how left_on accepts list of tuples. Tuples can be used to adress multilevel columns
pd.merge(a,b,how="left",left_on=[("name_0","name_01")],right_on=["name_0"])
```

If you instead use only the level 1 of multilevel column index in DataFrame "a" this warning disappears:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({("name_0","name_01"):[1,2,3,4],
                 ("name_0","name_02"):[4,3,2,1]})

# Only use the 1st level index (e.g. "name_01" and "name_02")
a.columns = a.columns.get_level_values(1)

b = pd.DataFrame({"name_0":[10,2,30,40],
                 "name_1":[40,30,20,10]})    

# Notice how left_on is now a normal string since only 1 level is used
pd.merge(a,b,how="left",left_on=["name_01"],right_on=["name_0"])
```

I suggest you check whether both your DataFrames have same level indices. If not consider dropping one level or flattening them to one level.

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be written this way:

`successes.merge(failures, on=['name', 'project_name'])`